# Passing Local storage data betwen pages using jquery

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I have array in my main.js page and I store that data in local storage using

//main page

```js
$j.each(response.records, function(i, record) {
            localStorage['sizes']=JSON.stringify(response.totalSize);
             var names=[];
            names[0]=getDate(record.StartDateTime);
            localStorage['names']=JSON.stringify(names);

            window.location = "theme.html";
});
```

//next page

```
   var size = JSON.parse(localStorage['sizes']);
   alert("Size in next page" + size);
   for(var i=0;i<size;i++)
   {
       var storedNames = [];
       storedNames=JSON.parse(localStorage['names']);
       alert("Stored Array value " + storedNames);
   }
```

record contain all data like date, time,location etc. I want to send complete record in next page, but in that page I am not able to parse that object. So I decided to send only date, but here count of date is 4, but in another page I got only last date store in array. So I store length of response in main page and fetch size in next page and after that loop is running, but again I got the same last value 4 times.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful to get the structure of the response object. Did you try to store the records with "localStorage['records']=JSON.stringify(response.records);" ?

Comment: I have to do this, but in next page I am not getting the complete 4 values, it returned me only last value.

Comment: Could you provide the value of JSON.stringify(response.records) ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

//main page

```
var names=[];
$.each(response.records, function(i, record) {
    names[i]=getDate(record.StartDateTime);
});
localStorage['names']=JSON.stringify(names);
window.location = "theme.html";
```

//next page

```
var storedNames=JSON.parse(localStorage['names']), allElements = [];
$.each(storedNames, function(i, el) {
    allElements[i] = el;
});
alert("Stored Array value " + allElements);
```

Comment: I'm glad to have helped you! Please mark as Answer for the other members (10x).